# SQL phpmyadmin SELECT and return multiple fields as string concat in a column of parent SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.
users, contents and categories.
so a user writes a content and selects a category for that.

```
categories                       users
--------------------------       ----------------------
category_id  category_name       user_id user_name ...

contents
------------------------------------------------
content_id content_creator content_category ...
```

so there are two references in **contents** table.

- content_creator => user_id
- content_category => category_id

**WHAT I NEED**: I want to have a list of all the categories, and for each row I want to show the count of contents containing that category and the users which used this category in their contents.

**WHAT I DID**:

I tried this query and it's working fine

```
SELECT ca.category_id,ca.category_name,
        COUNT(c.content_id) AS contents_count,
        COUNT(c.content_creator) AS contents_creators_count
        FROM categories ca
        JOIN contents c ON (ca.category_id = c.content_category)
        GROUP BY content_category
```

the result is as I wanted

```
category_id  category_name  contents_count  contents_creators_count
6            cat1           6               3
8            cat2           1               1
9            cat3           1               1
10           cat4           2               2
11           cat5           2               2
```

**QUESTION**: can I have all the **users.user_id** in form of a string or an array as a column in result?

like I tried this but it works for only one row

```
SELECT ca.category_id,ca.category_name,
COUNT(c.content_id) AS contents_count,
(
    SELECT u.user_id,u.User_name
    FROM users u
    JOIN contents c ON (u.user_id = c.content_id)
    JOIN categories ca ON (c.content_category=ca.category_id)
    
)AS category_users
FROM categories ca
JOIN contents c ON (ca.category_id = c.content_category)
GROUP BY ca.category_id
```

I want some result like this:

```
category_id  category_name  contents_count  category_users //based on user_id
6            cat1           6               63,88,125
8            cat2           1               63
9            cat3           1               88
10           cat4           2               88,70
11           cat5           2               null //like this category not used
```

Comment: Provide a sample as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO (or online fiddle). Show needed output for provided data strictly.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Strawberry i can do that easy by adding some code or another querry. i just wanted to see if i can do it in sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want string aggregation: MySQL offers `GROUP_CONCAT()` for this. If you want the list of (distinct) content creators for each content, you do not need to to bring the users table; that information is available in `contents` already.

So:

```
select ca.category_id, ca.category_name, 
    count(*) as contents_count,
    group_concat(DISTINCT content_creator ORDER BY content_creator) category_users 
from categories ca
inner join contents c on ca.category_id = c.content_category
group by ca.category_id
```

Comment: Now  I need something more. Consider some users who delete their accounts but they used a category before in a content and the content still remains on database. Can I count those users and add them all in total like this    >>>    category_users:63,72,deletedAccounts[0]     OR     category_users:63,72,0